# How to merge 3 table using union without join?

Tags: oracle, union

How i could merge table `employees`,`departments`, and `locations` with output with following this image?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulyS7.png)

I already try using this query but it return `last_name` and `department_id`

```
SELECT last_name Employee_Name,department_id FROM employees
UNION
SELECT department_id,department_name FROM departments 
UNION
SELECT location_id,city FROM locations
ORDER BY "Employee Name"
```

Comment: Union is to combine rows into a resultset. It does not help you join columns into a single row. JOIN is the correct way in this case. Exactly why do you want to avoid a join?

Comment: i have a task from my teacher to merge 3 table and he give me a hint using union to solve it

Comment: Does merging means create a resultset with all columns from all tables? In this case union all will hep 1nd you need to have the same number of columns oer select sub query:

Comment: something like select last_name, department_id from emp union all select null, department_id from dept;

Comment: Oh, i'm get it. thanks for your help